# The windows Service service on Local Computer started and then stopped

Tags: .net, windows, c#-4.0, service, windows-services

I have one windows service. The service code written in C# code. It was working fine earlier days. Suddenly the service stopped working. Even i have rollback my latest dlls, still its not working. I have tried with so many solution by doing R&D in google. But non of the solution worked for me. Still i am getting below error while trying to start the service.

The windows Service service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

I have tried this solution also.
https://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/service-on-local-computer-started-and.html

Kindly help me.

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I have fixed the issue. It was dll missing issue.

Comment: Have you seen event viewer?!! There are usually events related to service problems.